# Finding historical Air pollution data from Johannesburg

Tags: data-request, weather, meteorology

Where can I find historical Air pollution data from Johannesburg? I need hourly data (or a smaller resolution, such as 15 minutes, which is probabaly harder to find). Tried googling this online yet got no useful results.

The closest thing I found was [this](https://aqicn.org/city/johannesburg/) site, and it wasn't useful.

NOTE: by historical I mean from past years till today, 2015-2020 would be good for example.

Comment: if you dig around that site, there are historical downloads. as a hint, look for the "covid19 data" page

Comment: @philshem I found only daily data there.  I need at least hourly

Comment: you can try with this one, they have hourly data, but only for the last 48 hours it seems, https://www.iqair.com/us/south-africa/gauteng/johannesburg . Maybe you can use it to scrape and build your own data.

Comment: @SuperKogito Thanks! But I still need something to use for now, I can't wait years to build a db